# Is there any way to freeze the layer names in the TOC?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, table-of-contents

I would like to freeze the names of layers in TOC.
Is there any way to do this via QGIS config or PyQGIS?

I´m using QGIS Wien.

Comment: "freeze names" ... u mean forbid any name change ?

Comment: Exactly @snaileater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can (sort of) achieve it by modifying the QGIS layer tree model. Write the following code snippet in a QGIS Python console:

```
treeview = iface.layerTreeView()
model = treeview.layerTreeModel()

model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegend)
model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegendAsTree)
model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeReorder)
model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeChangeVisibility)
model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowLegendChangeState)
model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeRename, False)
```

After running the code, renaming layers (and groups) from the layer tree is no longer possible, although it can be done via the Properties dialog or via PyQGIS.

I guess that would be the most you can get.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference/embed the layers from a second file. (by using the "Layer - Embed Layers and groups" menu entry)

Layers that are embedded like that are read-only (so you can't rename them). You can move them around temporarily but those changes don't get saved.

Comment: Thanks @Max but not quite that. I need to keep editable layers.

Comment: Ok, didn't see that in your question. Hope you find out!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert but here's what i would do :

At startup maintain a **lookup table** containing the layer id and the corresponding name u want to be left unchanged.

Then i would use the layerNameChanged signal with a line of this kind :

```
self.curLayer.layerNameChanged.connect(self.watchName)
```

You do that for every layer of your project.

then in the slot "watchName" u try a :

```
def watchName(self):
    self.curLayer.setLayerName('the_right_name_coming_from_your_lookup_table')
```

I didn't write all the necessary code to create the lookup table.