# What is the correct way to run a python script in QGIS Open Project macro?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

This code (answer from @gcarrillo about other question - [Is there any way to freeze the layer names in the TOC?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147817/is-there-any-way-to-freeze-the-layer-names-in-the-toc)) runs fine on python console and inside a plugin.

But now, I tried put it within the "openProject macro" and it crashed.

The legend not appears and I get a minidump. How I can to make this? Or I can´t...

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.gui import *

def openProject():
  root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

  model = QgsLayerTreeModel(root)
  model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegend)
  model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegendAsTree)
  model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeReorder,False)
  model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeChangeVisibility)
  model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowLegendChangeState)
  model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeRename,False)

  treeview=iface.layerTreeView()
  treeview.setModel(model)
```

Comment: Tried it too ... same behaviour ... Did u solve it ?

Comment: I have not tried again ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is 5 years old but if anyone ever has a need for it :

There was no need to replace the model (which qgis doesn't like), you just need to access the model and do your modifications on it

```
from qgis.core import QgsLayerTreeModel
from qgis.utils import iface

def openProject():
    treeview=iface.layerTreeView()
    model = treeview.layerTreeModel()
    model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegend)
    model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegendAsTree)
    model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeReorder,False)
    model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeChangeVisibility)
    model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowLegendChangeState)
    model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeRename,False)
    
def saveProject():
    pass

def closeProject():
    pass
```