# Locking Table of Contents in QGIS

Tags: qgis, table-of-contents

I would like to customize QGIS for a custom use case where the user will work with a very simple customized UI and will just digitize features in existing layers.

Therefore the Table of Contents (TOC) should be locked, so that drag and drop reordering of the LayerTree will be blocked as well as inserting layer by drag and drop.

Is this possible?

Comment: does [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/147886/55203) help? In your case, you want to set AllowNodeReorder to False. Unfortunately I've not been able to get this to work in a Project Open Python Macro, which I suspect is what you need.